# I'm trying to get pyqt so i can get pylint but i cant seem to install it i am a absolute noob to python and coding in general

Tags: python, pylint

As stated in the title i cant get pylint. I'm on a mac using vs code and keep on getting this error

````
ERROR: pyqtwebengine 5.14.0 has requirement PyQt5>=5.14, but you'll have pyqt5 5.9 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pyqtwebengine 5.14.0 has requirement PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7, but you'll have pyqt5-sip 4.19.19 which is incompatible.```
````

Answer (score -1):

The dependencies aren't the right version, I'm assuming you probably used pip? Try

```
pip install --upgrade pyqt5
```

or whatever the equivalent version is for vscode. Then try again.